# Any way to add an entry into a Java arraylist with a custom position from an int variable?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Imagine there is a Java string arraylist called clients. Is there any way to add strings into it so that they hold a custom set position defined by a variable?
For example:  (I know that the code is not correct but just to give an example...)

```
class client{
public static int clientIdentifier = 6969;
public static String clientName = Peter;
ArrayList<String> clients = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

```
In the main method:

clients.add(clientIdentifier, clientName);
```

So that clientName hold the value of clientIdentifier in the array?

Thank you very much!

Comment: This sounds like an X Y problem. Do you just want to be able to get the `Client` (which should be capitalized, btw) by their `clientIdentifier`? You wouldn't want 6968 empty spaces before that, correct?

Comment: Sounds like you want a Map and not an ArrayList. A Map assigns keys by values, as opposed to keeping them in order, so Id -> Client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add elements to an ArrayList at a specific index.

```
list.add(int index, E element)
```

However, I believe a HashMap would be more suitable for this problem!
Here is how you can implement it using HashMap.

```
HashMap<Integer, String> clients = new HashMap<>();
clients.put(clientIdentifier, clientName);
```